# How to connect on remote database?

Tags: server, ssh, vpn

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

For a school projet I have to connect my local web application (which using Laravel 5.5) on a database (PostgreSQL) which is on a remote server (on the university network).

How can I connect my app on the database ?

We have this information : "You are asked to implement your database on PostgreSQL (server of the UFR, accessible in
VPN)".

Futhermore, we have the adress and the port of the server.

But I dont know how to connect to the network to connect to the server.

Thank's for help!

Comment: Do you have access to university network's cpanel/hosting panel?

Comment: It depends on how Database Admin set it up to access. I.E. with dedicated web address, local ip address(might require VPN). SSH will be complicated for a web page to handle.

Comment: In that case, Do you have VPN credentials? I.E.Certificate, Ta.key, Private key? This sounds like accessing a remote machine on the local network.

Comment: I updated my question with some informations.

Comment: We don't have VPN information, just the server adress, the port and the name of the network required.

Comment: Is the server address is a public or private address?

Comment: I think public adress when we are on the network.

Comment: You can try [these commands](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/001f01c018c2$830133b0$64898cd5%40northlink.gr) from outside of the network and if the switch or router is set up to route traffic properly, you should connect to the DB without a hitch.

Comment: First, connect your computer to the VPN, if outside the network of your university., then set up your application to use PostgreSQL with the credentials you have been given. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30480385/laravel-5-with-postgres-sql gives some information on connceting your app with Post. Ignore everyone talking about cpanel and what not. They have not understood the question

Comment: @vidarlo which VPN to use?

Comment: You have to check which VPN to use with the university. Often universities offer a VPN so students can connect to hosted services remotely.

Comment: Ok thanks! So it's not possible with VPN like openvpn?

Comment: No, the school runs a VPN infrastructure. Maybe they use OpenVPN. But you need a VPN connection to your school, not just to any random VPN server on the internet!

Comment: Yes yes I know that I need à connection with the school network. But I thought that any VPN could work to etablished the connection.

Comment: Has to be the same protocol as the other end. OpenVPN is one. Other likely candidates is OpenConnect (Juniper & Cisco SSLVPN). Check with your school. Often you can find the information you need using google.

Answer (score 0):

**Access Remote Database from local machine.**

*For this to work, you need access to admin access to cPanel/hosting control panel.*

**1. Login to your cPanel/hosting panel**

Login using your admin access credentials to your cPanel/hosting control panel.

**2. Add your ISP IP address to `Remote SQL` IPs list**

You can view your IP by searching `my IP` in google. If you are inside of a local network, most probably your IP would be allowed by admin.

**3. Get your hosting server/host IP address.**

You can ask your administrator for this or if you have admin access, you can get it from server detail page or cPanel.

**4. Use Host IP as host and remove database user credentials.**

Now, you can use your server IP as Host address and database credentials to access your remote database.

*This works with almost any operating system and application. I have also used this with my local PHP applications (CakePHP, Laravel, core PHP, etc).*

In your case, you can ask the server administrator to add your IP to allow remote SQL connection and then you can follow rest steps from step 3 to connect to remote SQL.

Comment: Isn't it quite clear that this is a managed solution, handled by the university? He's got credentials, and information that he has to use a VPN to reach the server. This answer is not an answer to the posters question IMHO.

Comment: I haven't used VPN. But VPN is used to tunnel through the network. The time I wrote this answer Nicolas was not sure of network type wether SSH or VPN. Even if you use VPN, you need the IP of the server and port to connect (if it is not being blocked by firewall or VPN itself).